# How do you place an element a fixed distance from the top of the browser?

Tags: css

I want to position an element so that it is always some fixed distance from the top of the browser so that even if the user scrolls down, the image will always be the same distance from the top of the screen. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No jQuery needed here. Pure CSS will suffice:

```
#element {
   position: fixed;
   top: 100px;
}
```

But if you insist on a jQuery solution, the code below sets the CSS via jQuery:

```
$('#element').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '100px'});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - but be aware that this will not work as you describe on mobile Safari (iPhone, iPad, iPod), Android mobile (any android phone or tablet), or IE6 (though for completely different reasons). If this is an issue, I can dig up some resources on them - just ask!

Comment: IE6 doesn't support it, because it's an ancient and feeble-minded idiot. The mobile browsers use a different scrolling method (you're essentially moving a viewing 'frame' around the page, rather than scrolling the page itself. Technically, this is correct - the element is fixed to the page. What we need is a way to fix the element to the viewing frame. http://cubiq.org/follow-along-floating-layer is a good workaround.